# Is is possible to have numbers from 2 frequent flyer programs for 2 passengers on the same reservation?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, loyalty-programs, air-france

I've just booked a flight from Canada on Air France for myself and another person, on the same reservation. We have frequent flyer memberships with different programs (Delta Skymiles, Aeroflot Bonus). Both programs are from Air France partners. I booked directly on the Air France website.

When trying to add our frequent flyer numbers on the Air France website, it did not accept the numbers for some reason (no error message, numbers just are not being added).

When I called the airline, the phone agent informed me that **they can't add numbers from two different frequent flyer programs to the same reservation**. This seems really strange to me - I've never heard of such a restriction with any other airline before.

So:

- Is this a real restriction?
- If so, where is it documented?
- If not, is there an official source somewhere that says it's ok to do this, i.e. to have two different frequent flyer programs for two different passengers on the same reservation? (I.e. some official document that I could point an airport agent to?)

Comment: This is probably a technical restriction, rather than a program restriction. But I've never been in a situation where people would fly on the same itinerary but want to credit to different programs.

Comment: If it's the miles you're trying to accumulate, the individuals on the ticket can add these flights to their frequent flyer account after the trip without having to go through an unnecessary hassle. You can normally find that option under _claim missing flight credit_ in your frequent flyer account.

Comment: @choster my wife belongs to SkyMiles.  I belong to Flying Blue.  We have done this on countless occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Of course multiple people on the same booking can credit to different frequent flyer programmes. Here's a test booking on Air France:
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, when I tried doing this on the Air France website, it completely ignored my frequent flier numbers (no error message, but numbers still not added to the reservation).

Answer (score 1):

It is at most a technical limitation in the system. 
Frequent flyer miles are given to the person *physically flying*, not who paid the flight or who owns the credit card or *who made the booking*, so the common booking is of no impact.

The easiest way is at check-in, each one have the agent enter his/her respective frequent flier number. You could even do it after check-in, behind security (when you typically have a lot of time left), at the service counters.